# gcc and clang both cannot compile a loop program

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, clang

I've been unable to get gcc and clang to compile this simple program I've written for an exercise in a textbook. The objective of this program is to accept 2 simple integer values from standard input, and then print out the 2 values to standard output. The program I have written is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch; cin>>ch;}

int main() 
{

  vector<int> vect;
  int number;
  int i = 0 ;
  while (cin >> number && vect.size() < 3) 
    {
    vect.push_back(number);
    }

  cout << vect << '\n';

}
```

When I compile the program with gcc, I get the following error:

```
Kohs-MacBook-Pro:Learning_C++ Kohaugustine$ gcc drill_chapter_4_v2.cpp -o drill_chapter_4_v2 -stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++
drill_chapter_4_v2.cpp:21:8: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'vector<int>')
  cout << vect << '\n';
  ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

The same error "invalid operands to binary expression" also happens when I try using clang.

Does anyone know what exactly is the problem here?

I'm really new to C++ and although I previously had experience with Python, moving to C++ is so different, and I've yet to take any formal introductory courses in programming, so please bear with me if this is a very simple problem. I would greatly appreciate any help to move forward!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't print an entire vector like that. Use a loop:

```
for (auto value : vect)
    std::cout << value << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `operator<<(std::ostream, std::vector<int>)` in the C++ standard library.

One could write one, such as this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<int> v)
{
   for(auto i : v)
   {
      os << i << ' ';
   }
   return os;
}
```

I should point out that iterating over the vector in situ is the typical solution, so:

```
   for(auto i : vect)
   {
      std::cout << i << ' ';
   }
```

would be what I expect to see in the code.

Comment: Isn't this overload UB?

Comment: I just fixed the `*i` - should just be `i`. Otherwise, I'm not sure what UB there is?

Comment: Actually it is probably OK. It is a question of whether by adding this overload you're adding something to the `std` namespace. "Something" can include template specializations but I am not sure where overloads stand. I'll have to do some reading.

Comment: Does that not apply to all `operator<<(std::ostream&, ...)` then? It's not like my code is doing stuff with the internals inside the `std::vector` or `std::ostream`...

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code

```
  while (cin >> number && vect.size() < 3) 
    {
    vect.push_back(number);
    }

  cout << vect << '\n';
```

the following way

```
  while ( vect.size() < 3 && cin >> number  ) 
  {
    vect.push_back( number );
  }

  for ( int x : vect ) cout << x << '\n';
```

As for the error then there is no `operator <<` for vectors. Either you should define it yourself or print out each element of a vector yourself using as shown above for example the range based for loop.